# Angular7 equivalent of C# attribute decorator

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a api method with an Authorize attribute that checks permissions

```
[Authorize(ReadIndexes)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndexes ()
{
  ...
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to decorate a method to check for permissions in Angular so the api call is not carried out if the permissions are not present

```
##????##
getIndexes(): Observable<Index[]> {
  // dont want to check in the method like below
  if(checkPerms("ReadIndexes")===true){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check guards https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are decorator but you have to write logic for the decorator

Example using decorator is component

```
@Component({
    selector: "thingy",
    template: `foo`
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

[This](https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c) is a blog post how you can write custom decorator

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `HttpInterceptor` in Angular where you can check authorization like

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, from} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {AuthService} from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class BearerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {}

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.authService.isLoggedIn())
      .pipe(
        switchMap(isLoggedIn => {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return this.authService.addTokenToHeader(req.headers)
              .pipe(
                switchMap(headersWithBearer => {
                  const requestWithBearer = req.clone({headers: headersWithBearer});
                  return next.handle(requestWithBearer);
                })
              );
          }

          return next.handle(req);
        })
      );
  }
}
```